# Kusto Query - Display most recent row

Tags: kql

I just started to use the Kusto query language. Still trying to grasp all of it.

So I have a query to get some SignIn events with a timestamp.
But I'm only interested in the unique values with the most recent date.

Distinct is not an option because all rows are different due to this timestamp.
Also the query returns too many results so it can't be processed.

Query to get all the logs is:

```
SigninLogs
| project TimeGenerated, Identity, UserPrincipalName, Location, DeviceDetail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `arg_max()` aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction.

And if that is done frequently - consider creating a materialized view with that logic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview

For example:

```
datatable(a:int, b:int, c:string, d:datetime)
[
    1, 2, "3", datetime(2021-09-08 15:05:10),
    4, 5, "6", datetime(2021-09-08 15:05:17),
    4, 5, "6", datetime(2021-09-08 15:05:43),
    1, 2, "3", datetime(2021-09-08 15:05:27),
    1, 2, "4", datetime(2021-09-08 15:05:53),
]
| summarize arg_max(d, *) by a, b, c
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2021-09-08 15:05:27.0000000 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 2021-09-08 15:05:43.0000000 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 2021-09-08 15:05:53.0000000 |

Comment: Already looked at it. It will only return one row instead of all rows.
I need al rows but only those with most recent date, where for instance the Identity is distinct.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't specify any group by keys, and thus got only a single row.

Comment: You were right Yoni.
Thank you.

I'm still new to Kusto Query and still learning.
I will check out the materialized view as well. It is indeed something I have to use quite often.